# Technique for proving stability of a linear system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

while I was studying stability for ODES (from G.Teschl ODE and Dynamical Systems) I faced this kind of problems which I have no idea how to tackle, thats why I'm trying to find the technique for solving them.

**Problem:** Prove that the equation $ \ddot {x} + (1+e^{t})x = 0$ is stable, i.e, all its solutions are bounded.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether it's the neatest way to do this, but I would first rewrite the equation as a system
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \dot y_1 \\ \dot y_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  y_2 \\ -(1 + e^t) y_1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Its only equilibrium is given by $(y_1, y_2) = (0, 0)$. The Jacobian is given by
$$
J = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -(1 + e^t) & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This matrix has pure imaginary eigenvalues $\lambda_\pm = \pm i \sqrt{1+e^t}$. Since the system is linear, this allows to conclude it is stable.